# For loop: paste index into string

Tags: r, for-loop, character

This may strike you as odd, but I want to exactly achieve the following: I want to get the index of a list pasted into a string containing a string reference to a subset of this list.

For illustration:

```
l1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
l2 <- list(a = 3, b = 4)
l <- list(l1,l2)

X_l <- vector("list", length = length(l))

for (i in 1:length(l)) {
  
 X_l[[i]] = "l[[  #insert index number as character# ]]$l_1*a"
  
}
```

In the end, I want something like this:

```
X_l_wanted <- list("l[[1]]$l_1*a","l[2]]$l_1*a")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sprintf`/`paste0` directly :

```
sprintf('l[[%d]]$l_1*a', seq_along(l))
#[1] "l[[1]]$l_1*a" "l[[2]]$l_1*a"
```

If you want final output as list :

```
as.list(sprintf('l[[%d]$l_1*a', seq_along(l)))

#[[1]]
#[1] "l[[1]]$l_1*a"

#[[2]]
#[1] "l[[2]]$l_1*a"
```

---

Using `paste0` :

```
paste0('l[[', seq_along(l), ']]$l_1*a')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `paste0()` inside your loop. That is the way to concatenate chains. Here the solution with slight changes to your code:

```
#Data
l1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
l2 <- list(a = 3, b = 4)
l <- list(l1,l2)
#List
X_l <- vector("list", length = length(l))
#Loop
for (i in 1:length(l)) {
  
  #Code
  X_l[[i]] = paste0('l[[',i,']]$l_1*a')
  
}
```

Output:

```
X_l

[[1]]
[1] "l[[1]]$l_1*a"

[[2]]
[1] "l[[2]]$l_1*a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do it with `lapply()`

```
library(glue)
X_l <- lapply(1:length(l), function(i)glue("l[[{i}]]$l_l*a"))
X_l
# [[1]]
# l[[1]]$l_l*a

# [[2]]
# l[[2]]$l_l*a
```